# Expression engine 3 -get the url of a channel entry

Tags: channel-entries, url, path

How do I get the url path for a particular channel entry?

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="work" limit="1" dynamic="no"}
    <h2>{title}</h2>
    <!-- link to url here -->
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is no such thing as an url in EE. You can however grab the url title like so: {url_title} however, you'll either have to do something like

```
<a href="(path="template_group/template"}">
```

(which i hardly use) or more harddcoded

```
<a href="{site_url}news/{url_title}">
```